# PowerShell replace a folder or files with an old ones

Tags: powershell, vmware

I'm buillding a script that will copy folder from a local server to a remote one. I would like the script to replace a folder in the remote server with the new folder that I copied from the local server. for example:

```
Copy-Item -Path \\local computer(win7)\c$\test.txt -Destination \\remote server(win8.1)\c$\test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way I've found to do this is use PSH to build a [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) command line and execute it.

With `/mir` option `robocopy` will mass update a whole directory tree very efficiently.